How to find out one's all-time ranking, percentage-wise?
This may be a bit of a petty question (and I'm usually not too concerned about rankings) but I wonder how to find out what one's all-time ranking is, percentage-wise. Currently I can see what my percentual ranking is for this year, but I can't figure out what it is for all time. Is there a way to do so?

By clicking on "top n% this year" you'll get to the reputation league. You have several possibilities there: week, month, quarter, year and all time. So you can see some ranking there - although not as percentage, just as the ordering of users.

@MartinSleziak Yeah I found that page as well. Hoping there's a way to find the percentage-wise ranking though

You can find a count of total users in the reputation league on the right hand side after scrolling down a bit - if you Ctrl+F for "Total Rep*" and divide your all-time rank by the number of users next to "1+" in the table, this will get you your all-time percent rank.

Probably it is worth mentioning that Stack Exchange recently removed "top N%" from users profiles - except of the top 400 users. This was announced here: Stack Exchange reputation leagues will soon list only the top 400 users. (The same is true about the reputation leagues - they now show only the top 400 users. The announcement was posted in May 2024.)
In the same place you can find an answer which gives some estimate of ranking based on a SEDE query.
For example, here is a result of this query run on Mathematics Stack Exchange with your UserId.
(You can change the parameters in various ways. You can change UserId to a different user and the parameter timeframe can be used to switch between year, quarter and month.)
It should be pointed out that based on data in SE you cannot find the exact reputation - for example, you don't have the data about downvotes you cast. The query is rather complicated and might run for a long time, especially on larger sites. (At the moment, this query does not include reputation from suggested edits. It does not remove reputation based on the offered bounties, either. Those data available in SEDE - but this would make the query more complex and more likely to time out an a large site.)
However, if you're interested only in the overall rank, the situation is much easier - the table Users contains a column Reputation with the total reputation of users. Here is a query which shows rank of the given user among all users ordered by the total reputation.

In a slight variation on rank you can use ntile and/or use the rank to calc their percentage position: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1843363/my-rank-among-all-users-ordered-by-total-reputation?UserId=53283. I'm not sure how a "you're in the top x%" can be expressed in a query where x depends on how close you're to the top (so for a low rep user x would be 50 or 25 or 10 but for high ranked users x needs to be (way) smaller than 1.
